# Really basic query working in PMA but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query

```
$db=mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_select_db('test');
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$r=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
print_r($r);
```

It only gives me the first element.

But in PhpMyAdmin it gives me all the elements.

How can I make it work in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches one row per function call. What you want is probably:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    print_r($r);
}
```